# jQuery update CSS in future elements part of div

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to do something like:

```
$("#div1 .code").css('display','inline');
```

Now the problem is that when I add another element with class "code" inside div1, it does not get the CSS tag of display inline.

How can I make it so that it always updates the CSS for any new elements part of div1.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

make a css class in the `<style type='text/css'></style>` section and add that class to each div that you make.  It is always best to keep styling and javascript separate, so it is easier to dbug and understand.

**edit** make the class `.inline-div { display:inline!important }` (use important if you want to make sure it takes precedence)

Answer (score 0):

Look into jQuery `live` events. They will do exactly what you need.

Comment: I've looked at live elements. But what event should I bind it to?

Answer (score 0):

`$("#div1 , .code")` -- the comma was missing.

look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717257/jquery-css-for-dynamically-created-elements) question

**Edit:**
You should bind with the event that creates the new element. 
How is the element created?