# Override existing style declaration with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<style>
  .thing { color: red }
</style>

<p class="thing">This is a nice thing</p>
```

I would like to change the ".thing"-style for all current content and all future content which comes to the page via AJAX.

```
$('.thing').css('color', 'blue');
```

This would work, but if new HTML code is added to the document via AJAX, all ".thing"-elements will still be colored red.

What I want is to change the whole style property ".thing" for the document and not only for the current elements (with a jQuery selector).

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery CSS() for dynamically created elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717257/jquery-css-for-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: No, i think they are doing something else.

In short what we need is a possibility to change existing definition of a style class. I'm aware of all different ways to change style with a selector or every time AJAX is executed.

Comment: The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717257/jquery-css-for-dynamically-created-elements/3717297#3717297) provides solutions both ways. You'd just modify it for your code. `$("<style>").text(".thing {color:blue;}").appendTo("head");` [Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/jjxB9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a style rule in the header with the DOM

#### Demo: [The Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/fRaxp/)

#### Demo: [DOM Mutation Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/fRaxp/1/)

```
var newStyles = document.createElement("style");
newStyles.type="text/css";
newStyles.innerHTML = ".thing{color:blue}";
document.head.appendChild(newStyles);
```

Comment: Worked like magic! I did change 'head' to 'body', because we need to override styles which come after some styles in the body. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a call back function on your AJAX code to run the jquery css function.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $('.thing').css('color', 'blue');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you are not able to use any of the techniques given in the duplicate question, you could modify the stylesheet itself, [for example](http://jsfiddle.net/LGmEp/2/):

```
document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].style.color = "blue";
```

However, the above line is not cross browser (I don't think it will work in IE, which prefers `rules` instead of `cssRules`) but it's possible to make it cross-browser compatible with a bit more code.

All it does is change the actual stylesheet, so it's like you had `color: blue` in there all along. This will affect elements currently on the page, and any that are added in the future (see the fiddle for a working example).

Note that you'll have to modify the indexes to suit your page. The indexes used in the example are just what work for the given stylesheet on jsfiddle.net.

**Edit** an attempt at a cross-browser solution:

```
var cssRules = (document.styleSheets[1].cssRules) ? document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0] : document.styleSheets[1].rules[0];
cssRules.style.color = "blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a style rule for blue text

```
<style>
  .thing { color: red }
  .thing.blue { color: blue }
</style>
```

and add **"blue"** class via call back function on your AJAX

```
$('.thing').addClass('blue');
```